# Eclipse PDT - find inexistent classes?

Tags: php, eclipse, class, eclipse-pdt

I have to remove a large functionality off our framework, and therefore remove all classes and functions based on it. As I've done this now, I want to check if I missed some code spots where the deleted classes and functions are still been called or used.

Is there a way to find code spots where nonexistent classes or functions are called? I already `grep`'d my mind off, it would be just to check if I missed something.

Thanks in advance,
Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Run your testsuite and see if it goes through. If it does, this is a sign that all functionality under test does still work. If it breaks you might have removed too many class definitions.

Enable error logging when you run the tests so that you don't loose any fatal errors that might bring Phpunit down.